# Как лучше разбивать таблицу InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

К примеру, есть таблица "products". Для продуктов нужно добавить поле "status" с их статусом (на модерации|активный|заблокирован). Как это поле лучше организовать?

1. Можно оставить его просто текстовым, но тогда будут храниться избыточные данные. Плюс ко всему, если захотеть переименовать статус из одного в другой - придется переименовывать все ранее добавленные продукты с таким статусом.
2. Можно выделить отдельную таблицу "products_status", и привязать ее отношением 1к1. Но тут тоже получаются свои минусы:

Во-первых при добавлении я не знаю какой id подставить в статус, и придется доставать сначала интересующий статус, а потом подставлять его id в таблицу "products".

Во-вторых кажется немного излишним для каждого столбца с несколькими вариантами заполнения создавать новую таблицу. От этого кол-во таблиц в БД возрастет вдвое, если не больше.

Подскажите как лучше быть, или возможно я в чем-то не прав.

Comment: Тут подойдет тип enum http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ENUM.html

Comment: От избыточности избавит, но если понадобится переименовать одно из значений, понадобится маленький бубен)

Comment: Спасибо. Этого вполне достаточно)